# Generate Rewrite Rule for Custom Taxonomy

Tags: url-rewriting, wordpress, url-rewrite-module

I want to add new rewrite rule for Custom Taxonomy and Custom Post Type but i am stuck with regex.

```
add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'my_custom_rewrite_rules');
    
function my_custom_rewrite_rules($orules){
        $rules = array ();
        $rules['([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$'] = 'index.php?city=$matches[1]&store=$matches[2]&page=$matches[3]';
        $rules['page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$'] = 'index.php?city='.$this->slug.'&paged=$matches[2]';
        $rules['$'] = 'index.php?city='.$this->slug;
return $rules + $orules->rules;
```

But When i try to access the following URL i get error **Page Not Found**

```
http://new-york.site[.]com/my-store/
```

But this Works:

```
http://site[.]com/new-york/my-store/
```

The Above Example Work Perfectly for Default Post and Default Category when i hook my function with:
**post_rewrite_rules** 
**category_rewrite_rules** separately.

### NOTE:

'city'  is Custom Taxonomy Slug.

'store' is Custom Post Type Slug.

Also consider i am getting correct Slug by using '$this->slug'

**So any idea what i am missing? if you need any more detail to answer this question feel free to ask, any help would be appreciated**

Comment: did you save permalinks settings?

Comment: Yes, it has Custom Base Like WooCommerce.
/store/%city%

Comment: sorry just seen what is failing, http://new-york.site[.]com/my-store/ this points to a subdomain?  You can't use wordpress rewrite rules to handle subdomains, it only works with what comes after your sitename. You can do it in your htaccess file though.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it worked with rewrite_rule_array, actually with other hooking i have already rewritten the URL it is just now WordPress which need to understand my request and it does with rewrite_rules_array thanks for your quick response anyways. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using generate_rewrite_rules i used

**rewrite_rules_array**

```
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'my_custom_rewrite_rules');

function my_custom_rewrite_rules($orules){
        $rules = array ();
        $rules['([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$'] = 'index.php?city=$matches[1]&store=$matches[2]&page=$matches[3]';
        $rules['page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$'] = 'index.php?city='.$this->slug.'&paged=$matches[2]';
        $rules['$'] = 'index.php?city='.$this->slug;
return $rules + $orules->rules;
```